# Firebase native for push notification require to use ngx in ionic3

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

Without using firebase native with ngx it gives error that firebase original is used as type and not as value in ionic3 app. If I update to ionic4 it keeps giving me some other plugin related errors. I want to stay on ionic3 and use firebase push notification

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { UserProvider } from '../../providers/user/user';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { server_key } from '../../app/app.angularfireconfig';
@Injectable()
export class FcmProvider {
userId;
fireuserStatus = firebase.database().ref('/userstatus');

constructor(
public userservice: UserProvider,
private http: Http,
public firebaseNative: Firebase,
public afs: AngularFirestore,
public platform: Platform
) {
}

// Get permission from the user
async getToken() {

let userID = localStorage.getItem('userUID');
if (userID != undefined) {
this.userId = userID;
} else {
this.userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
}
let token;
if (this.platform.is('android')) {
token = await this.firebaseNative.getToken();

this.firebaseNative.onTokenRefresh()
.subscribe((token: string) => {
this.userservice.updateDeviceToken(token, this.userId);
});
}
```

I tried removing node_modules folder. Remove platform android. Adding it again. running command npm i for installing node_modules folder again. Problem remains same

Push notifications should work. Right now messaging is working perfect but when I try to enable push notifications the plugin conflict comes in

Comment: can you post what error or warning you are getting.

Comment: how you are installing firebase plugin?

Comment: By using these commands
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
npm install --save @ionic-native/firebase

Actually I am following this piece of code. I bought it https://www.addwebsolution.com/addwebchat/support.html . The chatting feature is working fine. The new update they gave which needs to install native firebase. After installing it a red line keeps appearing below the word "Firebase". It didn't allow me to compile and run the project

Comment: if you add ngx then build succeed ?

Comment: Then the error of Firebase goes but Some other issue arrises in other plugins. There are alot of plugins so, I want to stick to the same code. I dont want to add ngx after each plugin. It will be a headache. Actually ionic4 forces you to add ngx at the end of some plugins

Comment: ngx is part of ionic4. u are using ionic 3 right

Comment: just install ionic 3 plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/firebase/) and don't use ngx in application and post all errors and warning so that will help a lot to understand your problems

Comment: Type 'FirebaseOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Type 'FirebaseOriginal' is missing the following properties from type 'FactoryProvider': provide, useFactoryts(2322)